# How to convert yyyy-mm-dd format to text format? (Ex: August 6, 2011)

Tags: php

How can I convert date format from 2011-08-06 to August 6, 2011 in php?

Comment: A simple google search will reveal the answer pretty quickly. Look through this page. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you need:

```
<?php
$mydate = '2011-08-06';
$datestr = date('F j, Y', strtotime($mydate));
echo $datestr;
```

See [`date()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Answer (score 1):

Format like this:

```
date("F j, Y", strtotime($date));
```

See [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: No that won't help me, I need to convert it from the yyyy-mm-dd format to August 6, 2011

Comment: @EdoDodo: Swapped votes then :) - looks like giving the link to the manual helps :)

Comment: @hakre Not like that, just didn't anticipated the string representation before he pointed that out :). I'm not that lazy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = "2011-08-06";
echo date("F j, Y",strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `DateTime` object with [`createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and spit it out with [`format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).